# NPOI reads wrong Formula value inside sheet data validation

Tags: excel, asp.net-core, apache-poi, npoi

For some reason, NPOI returns "A65535" instead of "F9" in Formula1 field inside data validation. I read all validations from sheet using `sheet.GetDataValidations()` method, and then analyze `ValidationConstraint` field for each validations. In a validation where a field numeric value should be less that F9, in `Formula1` field I get value "A65535", and when I open data validations pane from excel I see "F9".

Did anyone experience similar behaviour? This happens both with xls and xlsx files.

Comment: not familiar with GetDataValidation() method, but 65535 is the limit for an unsigned short.

Comment: That is also the limit for column numbers in xls, but still does not solve the issue. Seems that this is the bug inside POI, but I was not able to work it out.

Comment: However, it seems that it does work if I convert file to xslx (although I wrote it doesn't, but it seems my code cashed xls file while I was testing). XLS problem still remains. Also not sure if this is POI or NPOI problem.